# RDBMS that can reference remote database

Tags: database, relational-database

I'm developing a web application using PHP and an RDBMS. Some of the data my application needs are stored in a remote database owned by another entity. I have limited read-only access to this other database. Is there an RDBMS capable of executing a query to the remote database and using the result as if it were a local table (i.e. satisfying foreign key relationships, JOINing, etc)? I would prefer FOSS, but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL have the FEDERATED table type. You can create a table that references a table at a remote MySQL instance, and than use that table as if it was a local table.

This does have some limitations (e.g. no transactions support, IMHO), but it should work as you described.